# Solving $84m+165n=117$ over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have two integers $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and I would like to find in order to solve the following equation over $\mathbb{Z}$:

$$84m+165n=117$$

I guess we need to use the Euler algorithm but I'm not sure how. I have used it only when we spoke about one divisor. How to solve it?

Comment: I assume you mean you want to find $m,n$?  First, it helps to divide by $3$ to get $28m+55n=39$.  Then first solve $28A+55B=1$  That's small enough to do by trial and error (or just inspection, really).  To do it via the Euclidean Algorithm, see, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By the Euclidean algorithm, $\gcd{(84, 165)} = 3$ and $3 | 117$. Therefore your equation can be rewritten as $28p + 55q = 39$ where $p = 3m$ and $q = 3n$.

Let us try to find solutions such that $28p' + 55q' = 1$. We can immediately notice that $p' = 2, q' = -1$. So $28(39 \cdot 2) + 55(39 \cdot -1) = 39$ and $84(39 \cdot 2) + 165(39 \cdot -1) = 117$.

This is only one solution. Can you find a simpler solution, and then find the general solution?

Comment: I think you meant $28p+55q=39$

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction!

Comment: You mean that $3\mid 117$.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, $2×28-1×55=1\implies 78×28-39×55=39$.  Thus $n=78, m=-39$ is a solution.

Now the general solution is $(78+55k,-39-28k)$, as this is a [linear diophantine equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

Answer (score 1):

$\!\!\bmod \color{#90f}{84}\!:\ 33 \equiv\overbrace{ 117 \equiv 165n}^{\large 117\ \ =\ \ 165n\ +\ \color{#90f}{84m}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} \equiv -3n\!$ $\overset{\ \large \ \div\,\color{#c00}3_{\phantom |}}\iff \! \bmod 28\!:\ \overbrace{n \equiv 33/(-3) = -11}^{\large  \color{#0a0}{n\ \ =\ \ -11\ +\ 28\,k}}$

Cancelling $\,\color{#c00}3\, \Rightarrow\, 39 = 55\color{#0a0}n+28m$ $\iff m \, =\,  \dfrac{39-55(\color{#0a0}{-11\!+\!28k})}{28}= 23-55k$

Answer (score 0):

$165n=117-84m=3(39-28m)$ is divisible by $3.$ So $n$ is divisible by $3.$ So let $n=3n'.$ Dividing through by $3$ we have $28m+165n'=39 .$ We have $$165n'\equiv 39 \mod 28 \iff$$ $$\iff 165n'-28(6n')\equiv 39-28 \mod 28 \iff$$ $$\iff -3n'\equiv 11 \mod 28 \iff$$ $$\iff 9(-3n')\equiv 9(11)\mod 28 \iff$$ $$\iff 28n'+9(-3n')
\equiv 9(11)-3(28)\mod 28 \iff$$ $$\iff n'\equiv 15 \mod 28.$$ The main idea is in the 3rd & 4th lines above, where  an expression $An'\equiv B$  is multiplied  by some $C$ (that's co-prime to $28 $  ) to get $ACn'\equiv BC ,$ which reduces mod $28$ to some $A'n'\equiv B'$ in which $|A'|$ is (much) smaller than $|A|.$ So eventually we reach $A'=\pm 1.$  In this Q we only need to do this once.

So it is necessary that $n'=15+28 n''$ for some $n''$ (and hence $n=3n'=45+84n''.$) And this is also sufficient because $$84m+165n=117 \iff 28m+165 n'=39 \iff $$ $$\iff 28m+165(15+28n'')=39 \iff m=87+165n''.$$

Therefore $\{(87+165n'',\,45+84n''): n''\in \Bbb Z\}$ is the set of all possible $(m,n)$.